# IF Formula not calculating properly

Tags: excel

I've structured a formula that should spit out a numerical answer that is basically a simple sum formula with IF statements assigning numerical values to qualitative inputs. Apologies for the length, I am looking at a number of different factors.Formula is:

Cell `F36` contains:

`=IF(F32="Medium-High", 18, IF(F32="High", 24, SUM(F16, IF(F20="High",5,IF(F20="Medium-High",4,IF(F20="Medium",3,IF(F20="Low-medium",2,IF(F20="Low",1))))),IF(F24="High",5,IF(F24="Medium-High",4,IF(F24="Medium",3,IF(F24="Low-Medium",2,IF(F24="Low",1))))),IF(F28="High",5,IF(F28="Medium-High",4,IF(F28="Medium",3,IF(F28="Low-Medium",2,IF(F28="Low",1,IF(F28="N/A",0)))))),IF(F30="N/A",0,IF(F30="High",5,IF(F30="Medium-High",4,IF(F30="Medium",3,IF(F30="Low-Medium",2,IF(F30="Low",1)))))),IF(F32="High",5,IF(F32="Medium-High",4,IF(F32="Medium",3,IF(F32="Low-Medium",2,IF(F32="Low",1,IF(F32="N/A",0)))))))))`

`F16` - contains values from 1 to 5

`F20, F24, F28, F30, F32` - Are dropdowns, where you choose a value: Low, Low-Medium, Medium, Medium-High, High;

Right now, based on a test input, where:  `F16` = 5, `F20` = Low (1), `F24`= Medium-High (4), `F28` = N/A (0), `F30` = Medium (3), `F32` = Medium (3) my output in `F36` is 11, however doing simple adding, I should be at 5+1+4+0+3+3 = 16.

Where am I losing 5 points?

Comment: How is the expected output different from what the formula is returning?

Comment: The output is off by 2-5 points or so

Comment: I meant what are your inputs and what is your expected output?

Comment: We would like to know your algorithm of that formula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a table allocating numerical output to each qualitative inputs and using vlookup to get your output. For example, for a table created on K19:L25, the following can be used:

```
=SUM(F16,VLOOKUP(F20,K19:L25,2,FALSE),VLOOKUP(F24,K19:L25,2,FALSE),VLOOKUP(F28,K19:L25,2,FALSE),VLOOKUP(F30,K19:L25,2,FALSE),VLOOKUP(F32,K19:L25,2,FALSE))
```

**EDIT:**
Tried your formula and it gives the correct result. Maybe your 5 in F16 is not a numerical value? You can test it by using

```
=ISNUMBER(F16)
```

and it should give a TRUE if it is a number.

Comment: Looks like that was the problem. `F16` has a `VLOOKUP` formula based on an input in `F14`. It is pulling from a table with over 200 entries, all in Text format

Comment: Good to know that you worked it out. However as Simplicissimus noted, debugging embedded IFs is not easy. You should try to avoid them. Honestly, I didn't even try to debug yours.

Answer (score 0):

Debug embedded IFs is just hell.

What you are doing is recode a 5 levels scale. You may use alternative solutions.
a. place the 5 text values (from "Low" to "High") somewhere in a sheet, say in T1:T5, even better, give this range a name
then you can retrieve the values you search with

```
    MATCH(F20,$T$1:$T$5,0)
```

b. if it's suitable for your use, you may use combo boxes, presenting the 5 choices and giving the desired answer (from 1 to 5) in a linked cell.

(maybe not the answer, but I can't comment…)

Answer (score 0):

(This should be a comment but I needed the formatting capabilities of an answer)

This is the current logic of your formula:

- Check cell F32: "Medium-High" outputs 18, "High" outputs 24
- If F32 is neither of those, then SUM the following:

  - F16
  - Lookup for F20, F24, F28, F30, and ***F32*** where the lookup for each is:

    - "High" = 5
    - "Medium-High" = 4
    - "Medium" = 3
    - "Low-Medium" = 2
    - "Low" = 1

I find it strange that you first check cell F32 only to check it again later in the sum.  Because this current logic produces incorrect results, we can't really advise how to fix it without sample data and expected results.  My guess is you are summing too many lookups by including the F32 in there, but that's just speculation without data.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. What I've got is a scoring tool with several different interrelated factors (F20, F24, F28, F30, F32). Each factor is ranked from 1-5, or qualitatively from Low, Low-Medium, Medium, Medium-High, High, which I transfer back to a 1-5 scale. The issue is that for the factor in F32, if the input is rated as 4 or 5, that trumps all the other factors. However, if the input is 1-3, then I want the formula to calculate a result

Comment: @premiumcopypaper Is F16 supposed to be included as one of the factors?  Can you please edit your original post to show sample data and expected results?  Without sample data and expected results you're not going to get any additional help because we can't tell what the results should be or why your formula is giving incorrect answers.